# Zero Division in Python preventing program from running

Tags: python, python-2.7, division, divide-by-zero

I'm still toiling away on my multiple choice quiz program. I'm nearly there. Just a couple of bugs to still work out. The program keeps a running tally of the number questions you get right, wrong, and the current percentage. However, my program will not run because initially, the user hasn't answered any questions. Hence, they have NULL % correct. My code is below:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import math

right_answer_total = float(0)
wrong_answer_total = float(0)
answer_total = float(right_answer_total + wrong_answer_total)
percentage = 100 * (float(right_answer_total) / float(answer_total))

word_drills = {'class': 'Tell Python to make a new kind of thing.',
               'object': 'Two meanings: the most basic kind of thing, and any instance of some thing.',
               'instance': 'What you get when you tell Python to create a class.',
               'def': 'How you define a function inside a class.',
               'self': 'Inside the functions in a class, self is a variable for the instance/object being accessed.',
               'inheritance': 'The concept that one class can inherit traits from another class, much like you and your parents.',
               'composition': 'The concept that a class can be composed of other classes as parts, much like how a car has wheels.',
               'attribute': 'A property classes have that are from composition and are usually variables.',
               'is-a': 'A phrase to say that something inherits from another, as in a Salmon *** Fish',
               'has-a': 'A phrase to say that something is composed of other things or has a trait, as in a Salmon *** mouth.'}


def start():
    # For loop that creates a list named keys. It grabs 3 random keys from the dictionary word_drills
    keys = [x for x in random.sample(word_drills, 3)]
    # User is presented with a question. A value from the previous randomly selected keys is selected as the 'question'
    correctanswer = word_drills[random.choice(keys)]
    print "Question: ", correctanswer 
    # Set the variables key1, key2, & key3 to the 3 keys in the list 'keys'
    key1, key2, key3 = keys[0], keys[1], keys[2]
    # User is presented with 3 choices.
    print "\n\n(a)%s   (b)%s   (c)%s" % (key1, key2, key3)
    a, b, c = word_drills[key1], word_drills[key2], word_drills[key3]
    selection = raw_input("> ")
    print selection
    if selection == "a":
        if a == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            answered_correctly()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect..."
            not_answered_correctly()
    elif selection == "b":
        if b == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            answered_correctly()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect..."
            not_answered_correctly()
    elif selection == "c":
        if c == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            answered_correctly()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect..."
            not_answered_correctly()
    else:
        print "That is not a valid selection."
        exit(0)

def answered_correctly():
    global right_answer_total
    right_answer_total += 1
    stat_tracking()

def not_answered_correctly():
    global wrong_answer_total
    wrong_answer_total += 1
    stat_tracking()

def stat_tracking():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear') 
    print "-" * 37
    print "|         Stat Tracking             |"
    print "-" * 37
    print "| Correct | Incorrect |  Percentage  |"
    print "-" * 37
    print "|    %d    |     %d     |     %d %%     |" % (right_answer_total, wrong_answer_total, percentage) 
    print "-" * 37
    print "\n\n\n"
    start()

stat_tracking()
```

I'm not sure if there is a workaround for this, or if I may be going about it all wrong. Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't help but note some of the content of your strings. `def` can be used outside of classes. `self` is just a conventional name; in an instance method, whatever the first parameter is the current instance whatever it's named. This varies if the function is a class method, static method, or not in a class at all. Modules can also have attributes, and strictly speaking (if I understand correctly), methods are also stored as attributes; they just happen to be callable and so can have parentheses tacked on to evaluate them.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing meaningful to print out when no questions have been answered. Add a special check for a divisor of 0 and either print out 100%, or just print out N/A or something.

Also, here are some tips for your code.

```
right_answer_total = float(0)
wrong_answer_total = float(0)
answer_total = float(right_answer_total + wrong_answer_total)
percentage = 100 * (float(right_answer_total) / float(answer_total))
```

If you put `from __future__ import division` at the start of your code, all those `float`s are unecessary.

```
print "|    %d    |     %d     |     %d %%     |" % (right_answer_total, wrong_answer_total, percentage)
```

The string interpolation operator is deprecated. Use `str.format` instead if Python 2.5 compatibility is not necessary.

```
print "|    {}    |     {}     |     {} %     |".format(right_answer_total, wrong_answer_total, percentage)
```

Comment: is the string interpolation operator actually deprecated? do you have a reference for that? Google was not super helpful.

Comment: Well the documentation for `str.format` say "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code." So I guess it's not technically deprecated, but it is discouraged. Str.format is much better anyway. (More flexible, more readable, easier to use in common cases, and easier to use as a function.)

Comment: I totally agree it's easier to use `str.format`, thanks for looking that up :)

Answer (score 3):

Since at startup the user has not yet answered any questions, you could just set it initially to `0`.

If that gets a problem at a later point you could check for the zero division beforehand like this

```
if answer_total != 0:
    percentage = 100 * (float(right_answer_total) / float(answer_total))
else:
    percentage = 0.0
```

You might also consider using float literals (like `0.0`) to initialize your variables instead of using the `float` function to convert ints.

After you have fixed the bugs you might yet find, it would probably be a good idea to go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com with your code to get a bit of general coding advice.

Comment: Where would that if/else statement go? Into stat_tracking()?

Comment: It should go wherever you put the code to update the percentage. (Which you currently don't seem to do..) But `stat_tracking` might be a good place.

Comment: definitely. Not sure I mention this, but I've only been coding with Python for less than a month. Learning new things as I go along. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Change the 9th line to:

```
percentage = 100 * (float(right_answer_total) / float(answer_total)) if (right_answer_total>0 and answer_total >0) else 0
```